# Creating an email and username from the users name and surname? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

Right now I am making a small program which should create an email adress and username out of the users actual name. For example, Peter Anderson types his first and last name in two separate text fields, and the program should then return a username and an email adress in two separate textfields, once you press the save button. For example, Peter Anderson gets the username "a13petand" and the email adress "a13petand@test.com" a = autumn, 13 = 2013. It should only take the first 3 letters from first & last name. It should then append the first name, last name, username and email adress to the text area. This is how my code currently looks like;

```
package test5;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test5 extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    String[][] Users = new String[20][4]; 
    int counter; 


    public Test5() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void savebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (counter < Users.length) {

            Users[counter][0] = Firstnametf.getText();
            Users[counter][1] = Lastnametf.getText();
            Users[counter][2] = Usernametf.getText();
            Users[counter][3] = Emailtf.getText();
            jTextArea1.append(Users[counter][0] + ", " + Users[counter][1] + ", " + Users[counter][2] + ", " + Users[counter][3] + "\n");
            counter++;

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The array is full!");
            counter = Users.length;
        }


    }
```

How should I continue from here? How do I make it generate "a13" and then take the first 3 letters in the first and last name? That is my main problem. All I know is that I should use the String class method substring to pick the first 3 letters out of first & last name. And then use the Calendar class to get the correct year. But I don't know how to make it work with my current code, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String result = "";
result += new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(date).substring(0,1).toLowerCase();
result += new SimpleDateFormat("yy").format(date);
result += Firstnametf.getText().subString(0,3);
result += Lastnametf.getText().subString(0,3);
```

Comment: You could also use a string buffer, but I doubt it will speed things up much.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
firstName = Firstnametf.getText().subString(0,3);
lastName = Lastnametf.getText().subString(0,3);
currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
voila = firstName.concat(lastName).concat(currentYear);
```

or

```
voila = firstName + lastName + currentYear.toString ;
```